# My Huawei Ads are displaying only in some regions

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-ads

My Apk is uploaded to AppGallery and my Huawei Ads are displaying successfully using Cloud Debugging , but only when I change the region to a country that is located in Asia or Africa .
Ads are not displaying if the region selected is in Europe !!

Can you please help?

Cloud Debugging:

HMS Core Version : 9.9.9.999

Model and System Model: P40 and all other real devices listed in the Cloud Debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/site-and-country-and-area-code-0000001172734088?ha_source=hms1), Ads have the following sites:

- China
- Asia, Africa, and Latin America
- Europe
- Russia

Note: Ads Kit **cannot** obtain ads across regions. So if you want to obtain ads when region selected is in Europe, you need to set both the network and the selected region to Europe.

Comment: Thank you so much . How Can I set the Network if I am using Cloud Debugging? Do I need to change anything in my Code?

Comment: The code does not need to be modified. You can use a VPN proxy to change network.